# C sizeof for arrays - array vs. pointer notation as function parameter

Tags: arrays, c, sizeof

In C I can write a function declaration in 2 different ways (Which I was told are totally equal)

```
void test (int *arr);

void test (int arr[]);
```

But why we every need to use the first one? I mean the latter allows us to get the number of elements in the array using `sizeof()` something which isn't possible in the first one.

Comment: *I mean the latter allows us to get the number of elements in the array using `sizeof()`* **No**, it does not.

Comment: Many have already told you that your assumptions are wrong. Here another thing you can consider: You write: "But why we every need to use the first one?" For passing a single pointer to a function, perhaps. Would you really want to write `void test (int arr[]);` for a function taking a single pointer?

Comment: Linked duplicate does not actually answer the question, which is *not* how to get size of an array parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> I mean the latter allows us to get the number of elements in the array using `sizeof()` something which isn't possible in the first one.

No, that's not possible for the latter, too. Here is a misunderstanding of yours. Both notations are absolutely equivalent as function parameter and denote a pointer. `arr[]` does not denote an array nor a pointer to an array *explicitly*.

Take a look at here:

[C pointer notation compared to array notation: When passing to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298957)

You can only get the size of the array if you use `sizeof()` at the array name itself inside of the scope the array is visible or pass another argument/parameter to the function which contains the information about the size of an array from the previous `sizeof()` use.

You cannot use `sizeof()` at a pointer to an array to get the array size, neither in the function where the array is declared nor in another.

> But why we every need to use the first one?

To simple symbolize that it is a single pointer and not an array as this confusion in fact already brought you to here. :-)

Comment: Side Note: Next time before posting a question, you really should try it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean the latter allows us to get the number of elements in the array using sizeof() something which isn't possible in the first one.

This statement is wrong.
Both versions are in fact identical.
The function does not know the size of the array and you cannot use `sizeof` to get the size of the array. Instead you will only get the size of the pointer which the passed array decays to.

Comment: But why, in main if I declare an array I can get its size using sizeof()

Comment: @BigSur Because the declaration of the array is in the same function/scope you use `sizeof()` and don't use a pointer to address the array. That's a completely different scenario. You can't use `sizeof()` at a pointer to an array to get the array size.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean the latter allows us to get the number of elements in the array
> using sizeof()

No, it is not right information at all as to functions. After passing an array to a function taking the array as a parameter, the array decays into pointer thereby yielding size of the type's pointer type rather than that of the type per se.

For example for `int` type,

```
sizeof int
sizeof *int
```