# How to make a pointer to an array of string in c?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I want to make a pointer to an array of string(matrix[10][10]), but I get "initialization from incompatible pointer type" problem so how to fix it?
And what is the problem?

```
void rotate(char matrix[10][10]){
  
  char * pMatrix = matrix;
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j ++){
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i --){
      *pMatrix = matrix[i][j];
      pMatrix ++;
    }
  }

}
```

btw, my task is to perform 90 degree clockwise rotation of matrix, but my algorithm is terrible I know

Comment: @SaiSreenivas the same error appears

Comment: `char *** pointer_to_array_of_strings;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix` is of type `char (*)[10]` (pointer to array of 10 `char`).

`pMatrix` is of type `char *` (pointer to `char`).

There is a type mismatch when you use:

```
char *pMatrix = matrix;
```

You try to assign a pointer to an array of `10` `char` to a pointer to `char`.

This is why you get the warning:

> warning: initialization of '`char *`' from incompatible pointer type '`char (*)[10]`'

---

You need to dereference `matrix`

```
char *pMatrix = *matrix;
```

to get a pointer to `char`.

> Could you say why my version (`char * pMatrix = matrix;`) works for 1D array, but stops working for 2d array?

`matrix`' type is different when declared as `char matrix[10]` and parameter of a function. Then `matrix` is actual equivalent to `char *`. The assignment from `char *` to `char *` is correct.

Take a look at:

- [Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/)
- [Passing an array as an argument to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/)
- [C pointer notation compared to array notation: When passing to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298957/)

Note that if you provide an amount of elements like in your case doesn't matter. `char matrix[10]` is equal to `char matrix[]` which is furthermore equal to `char *matrix`.

---

<sup>No guarantee if your algorithm works beside that. If you got problems with that, please ask a different question.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways but I prefer this one:

```c
void rotate(char matrix[10][10]){
  
  char *pMatrix = matrix[0];
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j ++){
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i --){
      *pMatrix = matrix[i][j];
      pMatrix ++;
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could use this for better understanding

```c
void rotate(char matrix[10][10]){
  
  char * pMatrix = &matrix[0][0];
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j ++){
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i --){
      *pMatrix = matrix[i][j];
      pMatrix ++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, could you say why my version (char * pMatrix = matrix;) works for 1D array, but stops working for 2d array?

Comment: They both have different types when it comes to 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
void rotate(char matrix[][10]){
  char * pMatrix = &matrix[0][0];
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j ++){
  for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i --){
      *pMatrix++ = matrix[i][j];
         }
      }
   }
```

[image]

**One dimensional array:**

Consider an array a of 4 integers as `a[4]`.

Basic rule is both `a` and `&a` will point to same location.But they aren't pointing to the same type.
(1) `&a` will point to the entire array which is an `int[]`. The pointer type is `int(*)[]`

(2) `a`, when it decays to a pointer, will point to the first element of the array which is an `int`. The pointer type is `int *` Now consider two-dimensional array.

**Two dimensional array**

Consider an array containing two 1D arrays, with each of them having two elements; `a[2][2]`.
Since the number of dimensions increases, we have one more level of hierarchy i.e. `&a`, `a` and `*a` will point to the same location, but they aren't pointing to the same type.

(1) `&a` will point to the entire array which is `int[][]`. The pointer type is `int(*)[][].`

(2) `a`, when it decays to a pointer, will point to the first element of the 2D array which is an `int[]`. The pointer type is `int(*)[]`

(3) By using `*a`, we are de-referencing the pointer to a 1D array. Hence we will have a `int *` pointing to the first integer value of the 2D array.

**Now considering your case,**

(1) In your case is like the first case where you are just using 1 D array, and the one which I suggested as  `&matrix[0][0]`, the pointer points to the entire array. Hope this is clear now.

(2) Also, you need not pass the first dimension in the function.

Comment: thank you, it worked, could you say why my version (char * pMatrix = matrix;) works for 1D array, but stops working for 2d array?